# FirebaseUi - Error when extendsFirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: firebase, android-adapter, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am new firebase developer. I am creating an android app that use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.
I tried to implement my adapter extends from FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.
This is my adapter class

```
public ExamsListAdapter(Context context,Class<Exam> modelClass, int modelLayout,Class<ExamViewHolder> viewHolderClass,Query ref) {
        super(modelClass, modelLayout,viewHolderClass, ref);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(ExamViewHolder viewHolder, Exam model, int position) {
        viewHolder.textviewPublishSchool.setText(model.getSchool());
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        viewHolder.textviewExamineDate.setText(dateFormat.format(new Date(1467105484000L)));//sample with data 2016 Jun 28
        Picasso.with(mContext).load("https://techmaster.vn/fileman/Uploads/ImageBlog/Firebase-la-gi-29032016.png")
                .placeholder(R.drawable.exam_item_image_place_holder)
                .error(R.drawable.exam_item_image_load_fail)
                .into(viewHolder.previewImage);
    }

    public static class ExamViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        protected RobotoTextView textviewPublishSchool;
        protected RobotoTextView textviewExamineDate;
        protected ImageView previewImage;
        public ExamViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            textviewPublishSchool = (RobotoTextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.exam_item_textview_school);
            textviewExamineDate = (RobotoTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.exam_item_textview_examinedate);
            previewImage =(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.exam_item_imageview_preview_exam);
        }

    }
}
```

But I got this error message in constructor method

```
super(modelClass, modelLayout,viewHolderClass, ref);
```

Error.

> Cannot resolve method 'super(java.lang.Class, int, java.lang.Class, com.firebase.client.Query)'

Could you explain and help me resolve it ?

Comment: are you still using firebase.com instead of the new firebase.google.com? I believe the last argument in the constructor must be of `com.google.firebase.database.Query` and not `com.firebase.client.Query`.

Comment: You are right. Thank you